# Spline interpolation plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation, spline

i'm trying to output few graphs in the same plot using different interpolations in order to find the y when x = 5 and mark that point with a red asterisk. I did the linear and it's working good (means i get a good plot) but when i'm trying to output the spline plot it doesn't work very well (as you can see it only shows a line of asterisks). i would appreciate some help with understanding why it is now working?

This is my code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

%variables
y = [101.3 106.6 109.4 114.7 116.9 118.2 123.7];
x = [1.69 3.67 4.37 5.45 5.84 6.05 6.90];

%Linear interpolate to get pressure at v = 5 [m/s]
pressure = interp1(x,y,5)

%Spline interpolate to get pressure at v = 5 [m/s]
xx = 1.69:6.90;
yy = spline(x,y,5)

s = interp1(x,y,xx,"spline");

%linear plot output
hold on;
plot(x,y,'b.-')
plot(5,pressure,'*')
grid on;

%spline plot output
hold on;
plot(x,y,'o')
plot(xx,yy,'*')
```

and the plot:[image: plot for linear and spline]

Comment: We need to know what do you mean by "working good" and "doesn't work very well".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re plotting the single result of interpolating at 5, `yy`. You need to plot the result of the interpolation across the whole `xx` domain, `s`.

You were also plotting your original data twice. I cleaned the plotting and comments a bit, to make things more precise.

```
y = [101.3 106.6 109.4 114.7 116.9 118.2 123.7];
x = [1.69 3.67 4.37 5.45 5.84 6.05 6.90];

%Linear interpolate to get pressure at v = 5 [m/s]
pressure = interp1(x,y,5)

%Spline interpolate to get pressure at v = 5 [m/s]
xx = 1.69:6.90;
yy = spline(x,y,5)

s = interp1(x,y,xx,"spline");

%original data plot
plot(x,y,'b.-')
grid on

%linear interpolation single point
hold on
plot(5,pressure,'*')

%spline interpolation single point
plot(5,yy,'square')

%spline plot output
plot(xx,s,'+')
hold off
```

Note that you’re actually performing the spline interpolation twice, once for `spline` and once for `interp1(x,y,xx,'spline')`. It might be cleaner to get the entire spline structure back from `spline` and extract your interpolated values from it using `ppval`:

```
pp = spline(x,y);
yy = ppval(pp,5);
s = ppval(pp,xx);
```